# What is the fastest way to run this MySQL query that is sorted by count's increase & decrease?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table that records every single sales for 350+ products in a store; column includes product name and date.

I am working on a page that lists the fastest moving product based on the percentage of sales increase, but the query I have is very slow considering there are 350+ products and 60000+ records.

```
  SELECT product_name, date 
    FROM data 
ORDER BY ((SELECT COUNT(ID) 
             FROM data 
            WHERE date='$date2') - 
          (SELECT COUNT(ID) 
             FROM data 
            WHERE date='$date1')) / 
          (SELECT COUNT(ID) 
             FROM data 
            WHERE date='$date1') DESC
```

My MySQL knowledge is quite limited, so any help from the community will be appreciated.

Data sample:

```
| id | product_name    | date       |
| 1  | pen             | 2011-04-22 |
| 2  | pencil          | 2011-04-22 |
| 3  | pen             | 2011-04-23 |
| 4  | pen             | 2011-04-23 |
| 5  | pencil          | 2011-04-23 |
| 6  | pen             | 2011-04-23 |
| 7  | pencil          | 2011-04-23 |
```

Expected output:

```
1  Pen     200%  (3-1)/1
2  Pencil  100%  (2-1)/1
```

Comment: could you post a data sample and expected output?

Comment: You first have to ask yourself how you want to define 'fastest moving product'. Right now it's defined as: number of 'sales' on $date2 compared to $date1. And $date2 and $date1 can only be a single day (not a range of days). Is this even correct?

Comment: @frits-van-campen I think you are correct. I originally only compared from one day to another, but yours is definitely a good idea. How would you handle the query with this approach? Thanks!

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT .....` query and post the output to be able to optimize it.

Comment: @neurino Added data sample and expected output. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Eliminate a double select**
If you create a stored function, like so:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION SalesIncrease(OldSales integer, NewSales integer)
  RETURNS float
BEGIN
  DECLARE Result float;
  IF OldSales = 0 THEN SET result = 1; /*100%*/
  ELSE BEGIN
    IF NewSales = 0 THEN SET result = -1; /*-100%*/ 
    ELSE SET Result = (NewSales - OldSales) / OldSales;
    END IF;
  END; END IF;

  RETURN result;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now change the query to

```
//don't forget to escape $date1 and $date2 to protect against SQL-injection
$date1 = mysql_real_escape_string($date1);
$date2 = mysql_real_escape_string($date2);

$sql_query = "SELECT oldsales.product_name, oldsales.date, 
  SalesIncrease( COUNT(oldsales.ID), COUNT(newsales.ID)) as Increase 
FROM data AS oldsales
LEFT join data AS newsales ON (oldsales.id = newsales.id)
WHERE oldsales.date = '$date1' AND newsales.date = '$date2'
ORDER BY Increase ";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately when I am creating the stored function, I got this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN OldSales integer, IN NewSales integer) RETURNS float BEGIN DECLARE Res' at line 1` Ideas?

Comment: @Stephen, fixed the code in functions IN parameters are the only ones allowed, so MySQL does not want to see them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(d2.product_name, d1.product_name) AS product_name, 
       COALESCE(100*(COALESCE(d2.n, 0)/d1.n -1), 'Infinity') AS pct_increase
FROM (SELECT product_name, COUNT(id) AS n FROM data WHERE date=$date1
     GROUP BY product_name) as d1 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT product_name, COUNT(id) AS n FROM data WHERE date=$date2
     GROUP BY product_name) as d2
ON d1.product_name=d2.product_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC; 
/* BY 2 == second column, nonstandard SQL but works. Can also copy column expression */
```

**Make sure you have an index on product_name and an index on date.**

The `COALESCE` is to take care of the edge cases of no sales on one of the dates, as is the use of an `OUTER JOIN`.